AWS Presigned URL giving me badly formatted presigned URLs. Could this be the reason for ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error?
I want my react frontend to upload, delete images from AWS S3 using presigned URLs. I created a small application to test it out. Although I do get a presigned URL, the presigned URL seems to get into a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED tangle with the browser.
I tried to do a CURL, but CURL complains that it is a badly formatted URL the moment I put the presigned URL. CURL too gives me the same message - ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. I am not using AWS SDK for JS v3. This is v2 - I am in test drive mode. Once I get the flow, will upgrade to v3.
Here's my code
server.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { uploadURL } = require('./awss3bucket');
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static('src'))
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/src', 'client.html'));
})
app.get('/getPresignedURL', async (req, res)=>{
   const uploadUnifiedResourceLocator = await presignedURLGenerator();
   res.send(uploadUnifiedResourceLocator);
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('app is listening');
});

awsbucket.js

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ 
    region: process.env.REGION, 
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
 });
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

  const randomID = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000000)
  const Key = `${randomID}.png`;
const s3Params = {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
    Key,
    Expires: 3600,
    ContentType: 'image/png'
  }
  
const uploadURL = async ()=>{
    let preSgnURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
    Key,
    Expires: 3600,
    ContentType: 'image/png'
})
return(preSgnURL);
};

module.exports = { uploadURL}

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import axios from 'axios';

function Client(){
const [ file, setFile ] = useState('');
const uploadURLtoS3 = ()=>{
    if(file == ''){
    alert('choose an image to upload');
    return;
    }
axios.get('/getPresignedURL')
.then(
(res)=>{
axios.put(res.data, file).then(resp => console.log(resp)).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
const inputFieldChange = (e) => {
setFile(e.target.files[0]);
}
    return (
        <>
        <h2>Upload Image</h2>
        <input type="file" onChange={inputFieldChange}/>
        <button onClick={uploadURLtoS3}>Submit</button>
        </>
    )
}
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Client />);


The presigned URL that I get from the server.js code is of this form:

https://bucket-name.s3./%27ap-south-1%27;.amazonaws.com/6356661.png?Content-Type=image%2Fpng&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=%27K0000000000000000000000000000009us-east-1%27%3B%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240609T110931Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=0000000000000000000000000000f&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

Is this presigned URL badly formatted? Or is my code wrong? Or do I need to upgrade to AWS SDK for JS v4? or do I need to do something with my firewall/DNS?

The /%27ap-south-1%27; part of the pre-signed URL looks wrong. The DNS name should be something like bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com. Perhaps your process.env.REGION environment variable contains some unwanted quotes?

Thank you @JohnRotenstein it is working. The solution is to add all variables in the .env files without any quotes.

Based on @JohnRotenstein's comment:

The /%27ap-south-1%27; part of the pre-signed URL looks wrong. The DNS name should be something like bucket-name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com. Perhaps your process.env.REGION environment variable contains some unwanted quotes?

I found the solution was to add all variables in the .env files without any quotes.
